# New to website, reputation earning?

Tags: discussion

I am new to this website. How do I earn reputation so I can post images? Is it different from badges? I don't really understand.

Comment: You should have actually learned all that from reading the help section, which explains everything from the ground up.

Comment: Does the OP have the reputation to view this in meta?

Comment: @Liath Everybody can visit meta, no (otherwise SE would so something wrong)?

Answer (score 9):

[This link here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) should help you with any questions you have relating to reputation.

We also have a comprehensive help section detailing how many other parts of the site works [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help). I would also recommend you [take the tour](https://movies.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Plus you get a bronze badge when you're done reading the about page.